# Xcode C/C++ Mac OS Application перестала открываться консоль

Tags: xcode, консоль, c, c++

У меня стоит XCode 5.0 . Создаю проект Mac OSX Application, раньше при запуске того же Hello World, открывался эмулятор консоли и все было отлично, сейчас консоль не всплывает, но прога ранится и билдится успешно. Вывод в логах видно, но мне нужен ввод/вывод через консоль. Как отображать консоль?

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться, а зачем вам консоль?

Comment: Вы сравниваете пятый икскод с четвертым (что у Вас было раньше?) или еще с третьим?

Comment: @Ковальский, вероятно речь о консоли дебаггера. В тройке она еще открывалась отдельным окном и при запуске Run или Compile выводилась поверх всех окон